# Problem with mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a playlist table. I want to print tracklist from database. I have this sequence of data stored in database.

```
album | track | singer
----------------------
A     |   1   |  X
A     |   1   |  Y
A     |   2   |  X
A     |   3   |  Z
```

This way that is if track 1 has sung by both x and y combinely than I have stored that in separate record.  But at time of print I want to print in differect style...Like

```
album | track | singer
----------------------
A     |   1   |  X, Y
A     |   2   |  X
A     |   3   |  Z
```

What query should I fire to print it in desired schema, that is grouping it according to singer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
select album, track, GROUP_CONCAT(singer) from YourTable group by album, track
```